# Can "what" be a plural interrogative pronoun?

Tags: grammar

I searched Google Books for "what make you".

https://www.google.co.jp/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22what+make+you%22&tbm=bks&start=70

Here are some examples:

> God answered and said "Jesus held everything in his hands and he was human, he held the heaven and the earth, the earth destroyed itself three times and Jesus still had compassion for it, so **what make you** so worthy to bring this news to me?" ([The Next Level](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=H-wKi_kNBLsC&lpg=PA8&dq=%22what%20make%20you%20so%20worthy%22&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=%22what%20make%20you%20so%20worthy%22&f=false) by Qweon Lee Drayton-Washington http://www.fictiondb.com/author/qweon-lee-drayton-washington~the-next-level~454899~b.htm)

.

> Meanwhile, Baker was now holding a sawed off shotgun under the counter just in case Danny needed him for reinforcement. "**What make you** think that I would help you? Did you helped me when I went up?" Daniel boasted. ([The Bridge Back: Sisters, Cousins, Foes and Lovers](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=wdXydq2rIrwC&lpg=PA160&dq=%22What%20make%20you%20think%20that%20I%20would%20help%20you%22&pg=PA160#v=onepage&f=false) by Betty Ann http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Bridge-Back-Sisters-Cousins-ebook/dp/B0059HL63O)

Link to context

.

> "Don't be different," we are counseled, "go along with the crowd. **What make you** think you have an inside track denied to the rest of us? ([Speaking of Christianity:Practical Compassion, Social Justice and Other Wonders](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=lHFJCVJHU0IC&lpg=PA49&dq=%22what%20make%20you%22&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=%22what%20make%20you%22&f=false) by Robert McAfee Brown http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/481424.Speaking_of_Christianity)

.

> What make you think you are going to have a son, and why are you talking like
>   you're not coming back, Isaiah?" Orabell said, hugging him tightly.
>   (Our Time Has Come by Sylvester Stephens
>   [http://www.amazon.com/Our-Time-Come-Sylvester-Stephens/dp/1593090269](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593090269))

Are these sentences using "what make you" grammatically correct?

Comment: All of those sound really weird (and wrong) to me. I also note that they all occur in dialogue, which is more likely to preserve dialectal quirks.

Comment: @Wlerin: The first example is also dialectal.  From the same source: *"Everything was going fine in my life until my son die"*. There's enough instances of this on Google that it's probably common in some dialect; I don't know which one.

Comment: The first two of these are self-published and appear to have errors of spelling and grammar on every page. The third stems from a respectable publisher; I suspect that *make* here is just a typo.

Comment: @sStoneyB: Agreed; "made" would be correct.

Comment: @keshlam "makes" is more likely.

Comment: I'll also point out that the answer to the headline, as opposed to the question, is yes. ("I have some reasons for thinking so." "What were they?")

Comment: Note the second example also includes "did you helped me" - maybe this character is simply a poor English speaker.

Comment: @keshlam I would understand the subject of that sentence to be "they", rather than "what".

Comment: "Did you helped me:" shows that your sources are largely ungrammatical.

Comment: @Kris It's only one source that contains "Did you helped me", **not all** the sources.

Comment: @ivanhoescott: the first source contains *"until my son die"*, the second *"did you helped me"*, and the fourth *"free, what make me free. I ain't got no place to live"*. The dialog in the fourth one is quite clearly in AAVE dialect (its characters are black), the first sounds like AAVE to me, and the second is dedicated to a black soul music group, *The Dramatics*. So, no, *"What make you"* is ***wrong*** in standard English, but appears to be part of the African-American vernacular dialect.

Comment: @PeterShor Why do you think this question is off-topic?

Comment: @PeterShor "the first source contains "until my son die""
Who said that in the book?
In the first source, God said "so what make you so worthy to bring this news to me?"

Comment: @ivanhoescott Well, that settles it then: [if God said it](http://www.lolcatbible.com/index.php?title=Genesis_1&), who are we to argue?

Comment: I believe the narrator says *"until my son die"* in the first. I'm not going to look through the sources any more carefully, but for the first source, it looks to me as if the whole thing is written in language heavily influenced by AAVE. In the second and fourth, the characters (or at least many of them) speak in AAVE. The third is in standard English, except that the author quotes somebody as saying *"what make you think"*. I don't know if that's a typo, or if he's quoting somebody speaking dialect. Either seems possible.

Comment: @tchrist "if God said it, who are we to argue?" It's a fiction. The author wrote it.

Comment: I think the answer to the actual question can be found here [Plural *What*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/which-is-the-correct-question-who-has-vs-who-have/31139#31139). It's a bit of a high level answer, and includes info from vetted grammar sources, but its very clearly explained, imo :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no. At least, not in the standard dialect.

That is to say, when "what" is the *subject* of an interrogative clause, and the immediate context provides no indication of what quantity is expected in the answer, then "what" takes a singular verb. If "what" is instead the object, as in "What have you done?", or the old Shakespearean "What make you...", then the verb will agree with the true subject (in these cases, "you"), not with "what". If the verb is a form of to be, and the verb complement is plural, then the verb can agree instead with the complement.

Note: This only applies when "what" is used as an interrogative, and what it refers to is still unknown. It does not apply when the referent is known, as when it is used as a relative pronoun, e.g. "The stars are what light up the night." If the identity of the referent is still unknown, but its *number* (singular or plural) *is* known from the immediate context, then what can sometimes take a plural verb. It is rarely, if ever, required to do so, however.

For more information on this last point, and a slightly different take on the grammar of interrogative what, including citations from CGEL, see [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/which-is-the-correct-question-who-has-vs-who-have/31139#31139).

Comment: That's just plain GR, isn't that?

Comment: In today's standard English, the answer to the question in the OP's title is "yes". The interrogative "what" can sometimes be plural, w.r.t. subject-verb agreement. There is this example: *"What are going to be the deciding factors?"*, and the info within this answer post includes excerpts from vetted grammatical sources: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31139/8758

Comment: @F.E. Thank you for that. I'm not sure that particular example is cogent: it sounds awkward, suggesting a disruption of word order for rhetorical effect. Supporting this, the near-identical "What are the deciding factors going to be?" feels much more natural, and here the subject is clearly *factors*, not *what*. The link does provide less questionable sentences, though.

Comment: @F.E. Even if it didn't sound awkward, that verb in that sentence is a form of to be, which can agree in number with its complement. e.g. "What are they?"

Comment: @F.E. I've modified my answer slightly to attempt to account for these exceptions, and would appreciate your input again. I've tried to err on the side of remaining succinct, though that's not exactly something I'm good at...

Comment: @F.E. Your comment appears to be here! :)

Comment: @Araucaria I had put a similar comment under the OP's question post, but it had been deleted by someone other than me. Weird. *shrugs* (I'm guessing someone didn't like seeing a solid grammatical answer, though it was a comment. This isn't the first time that this has happened, by the way.)

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Pronouns replace nouns. When the replaced noun is plural, "what" takes a plural verb, so it is a plural interrogative. Your first and second examples use the phrase "what make you" grammatically correctly. "Earth" is "you people of earth", so plural. The third example is less clear, but still seems to refer to a plural.   The second example appears to be dialectical or perhaps substandard speech

Comment: It's an interrogative pronoun. You don't know yet what it's replacing. Second example is definitely dialectal, though ("Did you helped").

Comment: I answered yes, because there are standard uses of "what" with a plural verb. Example: "What do you know?"

Comment: But in *"what do you know?"* the subject is *you*. Consider *"what does he know?"* where the subject is *he*. And in *"what are the chief exports of Ruritania"*, the subject is *"exports"*. I wouldn't say *"what live in these holes"*, even though *what* is clearly standing for something plural there.

Comment: @Theresa You are [not alone in asserting this](http://www.testden.com/toefl/english-grammar-for-students/Interrogative-Pronouns.html), however, I believe both you and that site mistake the subject of the plural verb in your examples.

Comment: I can envision an exchange like "These are broken." "_What_ are broken?"

Comment: @MattGutting You may have a point with that one. In this case, although the referent is still unknown, its number isn't. Still... in that exchange the "what" is just being dropped into an existing sentence.

Comment: This is interesting. I should get a pencil and diagram some sentences. (Yes, I am ancient.) Here's a Momism: "What are these toy ships doing in the bathtub?" Subject, ships; verb, are; what, object? Seems to me that  if "what" is a pronoun, it will usually be the object of the verb. Interrogatory;  yes, still pronoun of undefined number.

Comment: That sentence is the same as: "These toy ships are doing what in the bathtub?" "What" is the object of are doing. When it is an object, there isn't really any way to tell what "number" it has. However, it is possible for "what" to be a subject, as in "What makes you think English is hard to learn?" and most (all?) of the time, in such cases, it is treated as singular.